# Run plugin execution before a plugin runs

Tags: java, maven

I am using [Spotify's docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) to package one of my services into a Docker container. The image is created by executing `mvn docker:build`. The issue I have is that I need to run some Maven target's inorder to place everything in the expected place, e.g. copy the transitive dependency closure into the `target/` directory. I have the following POM file:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
          <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
          <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.11</version>
    <configuration>
      <imageName>${project.name}-image</imageName>
      <baseImage>java</baseImage>
      <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/runtime-environment/lib/${project.build.finalName}.jar", "-classpath", "/runtime-environment/lib/*"]</entryPoint>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <targetPath>/runtime-environment/lib/</targetPath>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
          <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
        </resource>
        <resource>
          <targetPath>/runtime-environment/lib/</targetPath>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
          <include>**/*</include>
        </resource>
      </resources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

How can I run `copy-dependencies` only before `docker:build` is run?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin#usage). Bind the `docker:build` goal to the package phase by adding the `executions` section, and run the `package` goal instead of `docker:build`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.11</version>
    <configuration>
      <imageName>${project.name}-image</imageName>
      <baseImage>java</baseImage>
      <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/runtime-environment/lib/${project.build.finalName}.jar", "-classpath", "/runtime-environment/lib/*"]</entryPoint>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <targetPath>/runtime-environment/lib/</targetPath>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
          <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
        </resource>
        <resource>
          <targetPath>/runtime-environment/lib/</targetPath>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</directory>
          <include>**/*</include>
        </resource>
      </resources>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>build</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I don't want to bind `docker:build` to `package`. What I would like is: "If `docker:build` is to be run, first run `copy-dependencies`." What you have is: "Run `copy-dependencies` and `docker:build` on every package phase."

Comment: @Max -  you can create a profile that includes this configuration and activate it only when you want.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your use of the dependency-plugin: your `<configuration>` is nested below `<executions>` which makes your configuration only available inside one or more phases of the standard maven build lifecycle.

My guess is the following:

1) put your dependency-plugin `<configuration>` on the same level as you put it for your docker-maven-plugin (directly under `<plugin>`).

2) run `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies docker:build`

Please let me know if it worked.